# How to keep specific element indexs in an array

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing

Suppose I have two arrays:

```
a = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
b = [2,5,7]
```

And I want to keep the elements indexed in a that are listed in b so the 2nd, 5th and 7th index of a:

```
a_new = [4, 25, 49]
```

I will then plot b against a_new / perform analysis on it.

For my application, a is a long series of simulated data, and b is a time series of when I want to sample from this data.

Thanks

Comment: `a_new = [a[i-1] for i in b]`

Comment: a_new = [a[i - 1] for i in b]

Comment: Could you explain how that works? I'm getting a 'list index out of range' error. Thanks

Comment: `a` and `b` are lists, not arrays.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remember that the first element of an array (or in this case a list) is number 0 and not number 1:

```
a = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
a[0] = 1   # How to adress the first element
a[1] = 4   # How to adress the second element
a[2] = 9   # ...
```

So the elements you want (as specified in the array b) are:

```
a[1] = 4    # a[1] is the same as a[2 - 1] (note that b[0] = 2)
a[4] = 25   # a[4] is the same as a[5 - 1] (note that b[1] = 5)
a[6] = 49   # a[6] is the same as a[7 - 1] (note that b[2] = 7)
```

So you can also access the elements this way:

```
a[ b[0] - 1 ] = 4    # Same as a[1] which is the second element
a[ b[1] - 1 ] = 25   # Same as a[4] which is the fifth element
a[ b[2] - 1 ] = 49   # Same as a[6] which is the seventh element
```

This can be wrapped up in a for-loop:

```
a_new = []    # Start with an empty list
for index in b:   # index in b are all elements in b, thus: b[0] = 2, b[1] = 5 and b[2] = 7
    a_new.append(a[ index - 1])
```

This loop will put the elements `a[2 - 1]` (4), `a[5 - 1]` (25) and `a[7 - 1]` (49) into the list`a_new`.

But there is a shorter way to write that loop:

```
a_new = [ a[ index - 1] for index in b ]
```

Basically, you say `a_new = [ ... ]`, so `a_new` is a list, and the `...` inside will specify, what the list will be filled with. In this case, it will be the elements that the for-loop produces, note that `a[ index - 1] for index in b` is  the same for-loop as in the first example, written in a compact way.

**What if you get an list index out of range error?**

Your list`a` contains 9 elements, so the first element is `a[0]` and the last is `a[8]`. If you try to access any other element in a list, for example `a[12]`, you will get a "list index out of range" error.

That means: the list b should only contain numbers between 1 and 9 (the length of the list, which you can find out this way `len[a] = 9`).

**I would recommend**, that you change your list b to `b = [1, 4, 6]`, since the fifth element of an array is actually adressed like `a[4]` and not `a[5]`.

The code will be a bit easier:

```
a_new = [ a[index] for index in b ]
```

If you don't want errors to happen, the values in b should then be between 0 and 8 (which is `len(a) - 1`), since `a[0]` is the first and `a[8]` is the last element, and only elements between that exist!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, very helpful for a beginner!

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible problems that you may be encountering, both of which have been somewhat mentioned in the comments. From what I see, you either have a problem reading the or you have an invalid index in `b`.

For the former, you may actually want

```
a = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
b = [2,5,7]
```

To produce:

```
a_new = [9, 36, 64]
```

Since you always count starting from zero:

```
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
 0  1  2  3   4   5   6   7   8
```

Hence, leading to an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), where you try to solve a problem *your way* which is the wrong way. Therefore, it wastes our time to try to fix a problem that doesn't work since it is actually something else.

However, for the latter, you may have an anomaly in your `b` list. The way to index the list (given in the comments) as you wanted is using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
a_new = [a[i-1] for i in b]
```

What this does is:

```
a_new = []
for i in b:
    a_new.append(a[i-1])
```

Hence, when `i` is larger than or equal to `len(a)`, it evaluates to an invalid index:

```
>>> a = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
>>> len(a)
9
>>> a[9]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, very helpful for a beginner :)